# How can I get all sub-sites from a specific sitecollections with Search Rest API?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, rest

I am using the Search REST API.

With this following url I get all sites:

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=50&refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Web")'
```

But I would like to only get all sub-sites from example `http://local/teamsites/` and `http://local/Supportsites/`.

Is it possible?

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

Just add `path:http://local/teamsites/* OR path:http://local/Supportsites/*` to your query, like so:

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='path:http://local/teamsites/* OR path:http://local/Supportsites/*'&trimduplicates=false&rowlimit=50&refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Web")'
```

Comment: where will i add this code? can I add this inside a CEWP / script editor web part ?